# How to replace an excel file column according to the column of another file

Tags: java, excel, csv

country.csv --> I have an excel file that contains countries and their codes as well as region
city.csv --> Another excel file contains cities and countries

The extension of the file is no problem it could be *.csv or *.xls

I intend to replace `city.csv` COUNTRY as `country.csv` COUNTRY_CODE

The sample data of city.csv file is as under:

```
City_Code   City            Airport         Country
AAA         Anaa            Anaa            French Polynesia
AAB         Arrabury        Arrabury        Australia
AAC         Arish           El Arish        Egypt
AAD         Ad-Dabbah       Ad-Dabbah       Sudan
AAE         Annaba          Les Salines     Algeria
AAF         Apalachicola    Municipal       USA
AAG         Arapoti         Arapoti         Brazil
```

The country.csv sample data is as following:

```
Country     Country_Code    Region_Code
Afghanistan     AF             AS
Albania         AL             EU
Algeria         DZ             AF
American Samoa  AS             OC
Andorra         AD             EU
```

I am looking for any solution either related to excel/csv or using Java

Best regards

Comment: Take a look at [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open both spreadsheets in xls
2. Use an XLOOKUP formula (VLOOKUP in older excel versions) next to the country column
3. Copy the new column
4. Paste **Values** into the country column